# Semantic exception error in HIVE while using last_value window function

Tags: hive, hiveql, window-functions

I have a table with the following data:

```
dt  device  id  count
2018-10-05  computer    7541185957382   6
2018-10-20  computer    7541185957382   3
2018-10-14  computer    7553187775734   6
2018-10-17  computer    7553187775734   10
2018-10-21  computer    7553187775734   2
2018-10-22  computer    7549187067178   5
2018-10-20  computer    7553187757256   3
2018-10-11  computer    7549187067178   10
```

I want to get the last and first `dt` for each `id`. Hence, I used the window functions first_value and last_value as follows:

```
select id,last_value(dt) over (partition by id order by dt) last_dt
from table
order by id
;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
Underlying error: Primitve type DATE not supported in Value Boundary expression
```

I am not able to diagnose the problem, and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add **rows between** clause in your query, then your query will work fine.

```
hive> select id,last_value(dt) over (partition by id order by dt 
      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) last_dt 
      from table order by id;
```

**Result:**

```
+----------------+-------------+--+
|       id       |   last_dt   |
+----------------+-------------+--+
| 7541185957382  | 2018-10-20  |
| 7541185957382  | 2018-10-20  |
| 7549187067178  | 2018-10-22  |
| 7549187067178  | 2018-10-22  |
| 7553187757256  | 2018-10-20  |
| 7553187775734  | 2018-10-21  |
| 7553187775734  | 2018-10-21  |
| 7553187775734  | 2018-10-21  |
+----------------+-------------+--+
```

There is [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13973) regards to primitive type support and got fixed in **Hive.2.1.0**

**UPDATE:**

For distinct records you can use **ROW_NUMBER** window function and filter out only the `first row` from the result set.

```
hive> select id,last_dt from 
          (select id,last_value(dt) over (partition by id order by dt 
              rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) last_dt,
              ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by dt)rn 
              from so )t 
           where t.rn=1;
```

**Result:**

```
+----------------+-------------+--+
|       id       |     dt      |
+----------------+-------------+--+
| 7541185957382  | 2018-10-20  |
| 7553187757256  | 2018-10-20  |
| 7553187775734  | 2018-10-21  |
| 7549187067178  | 2018-10-22  |
+----------------+-------------+--+
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. One question, is there a way to get only the `distinct rows` without writing a `select distinct` statement on top . As can be seen in the result above, there are duplicates. How to remove them and get only the unique values without `sub-query` in one go.

Comment: @Raj,Please check my edited answer's **UPDATE** section, easier way would be adding `distinct` on top but we can also make use of `row_number` window function in sub-query.