# Hive windowing in sub-query and outer query on DATE

Tags: hive, boundary

```
CREATE TABLE big_hive_table(
`partner` string,
start_date date,
end_date date,
`category` string,
`category2` string);

insert into big_hive_table values ('S1','2018-01-01','2018-03-31','c1','M');
insert into big_hive_table values ('S1','2017-12-01','2018-01-31','c1','M');
insert into big_hive_table values ('S1','2017-01-01','2017-11-30','c1','M');
insert into big_hive_table values ('S1','2018-02-01','2018-04-30','c1','M');
insert into big_hive_table values ('S1','2018-02-01','2018-04-30','c1','L');
insert into big_hive_table values ('S2','2018-02-01','2018-04-30','c1','S');
insert into big_hive_table values ('S3','2018-02-01','2018-04-30','c2','S');
insert into big_hive_table values ('S3','2018-01-01','2018-03-31','c2','S');
insert into big_hive_table values ('S3','2017-12-01','2018-01-31','c2','S');
```

Problem: get oldest start_date and latest end_date for the group (partner, `category`, `category2`) if there is an overlapping period

```
expected result: 

S1  01/12/2017  30/04/2018  c1  M
S1  01/01/2017  30/11/2017  c1  M
S1  01/02/2018  30/04/2018  c1  L
S2  01/02/2018  30/04/2018  c1  S
S3  01/12/2017  30/04/2018  c2  S
```

My query

```
SELECT DISTINCT partner, 
                category, 
                category2, 
                First_value(start_date) OVER (partition BY partner, category, category2 ORDER BY start_date) period_start,
                last_value(end_date) OVER (partition BY partner, category, category2 ORDER BY start_date rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED following) period_end
from (select pps.*, sum(start_new_period) over (partition BY partner, category, category2)
    FROM ( select partner, 
            start_date,
            end_date, 
            category, 
            category2, 
            lag(end_date) over (partition by partner, category, category2 order by start_date) previous_period_end
            , case 
                when start_date > lag(end_date) over (partition by partner, category, category2 order by start_date) 
                then 1 
                else 0 
                end start_new_period
            from big_hive_table
            where start_date is not null and end_date is not null) pps
)
```

Currently I'm getting the following error, when I run 2 inner queries (from select pps.*) or the whole query:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException:Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
Underlying error: Primitve type DATE not supported in Value Boundary expression
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm missing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I missed alias for the outer most query. please add alias if you are testing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add  **`rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED following`** in your **first_value** window function and try running again.

**Change your query**

**from**

```
First_value(start_date) OVER (partition BY partner, category, category2 
ORDER BY start_date) period_start
```

**To**

```
First_value(start_date) OVER (partition BY partner, category, category2 ORDER BY
 start_date rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED following) period_start
```

There is [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13973) regards to primitive type support and got fixed in Hive.2.1.0

Comment: Thanks @Shu but it didn't help. I believe this issue not related to HIVE-13973, as I can run the inner most query with windowing on date without issues.

Comment: @DE2018, If we are using **lead,lag** functions then we don't need to specify rows between clause but if we are using **first_value,last_value** on `date` datatype`(Hive < 2.0)` then we need to specify rows between clause.

Comment: @DE2018, for more details regards to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979610/semantic-exception-error-in-hive-while-using-last-value-window-function/52979898#52979898